# Maximizing a vector after a series of matrix multiplications

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, oc.optimization-and-control, combinatorial-optimization

## Problem Statement

Let's say we have a set of $n\times n$ matrices $X=\{M_1,\ldots,M_r\}$ and weights of these matrices $\{w_1,\ldots,w_r\}$ along with a set of "initial vectors" $\{v_1,\ldots,v_s\}$. We then define the weight of a vector $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ by

$$w(u)=\min\{x:\big(\exists i_1,\ldots,i_k,j:x=w_{i_1}+\cdots+w_{i_k},u=M_{i_1}\cdots M_{i_k}v_j \big)\}\textrm{ or }w(u)=\infty\textrm{ if this set is empty}$$

Finally, we introduce a function $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ which we wish to maximize. We can then ask questions like "what is the maximum value of $f$ over all vectors of weight at most some $y$?", or "given $x$, what is the minimum weight of a vector $u$ satisfying $f(u)\geq x$?". We can also ask for the most efficient algorithm to answer these questions, or if a closed form exists.

I am very curious if this general question has been studied at all. Are there any known results in this area? Any references or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

## Motivation

An example of a problem which can be formulated as above is the $UwU$ problem. In this problem, Alice wants to send Bob as many $UwU$'s as possible. She starts by manually typing "$UwU$" and afterwards has two options at each step: copy everything she has already written (which takes $kp$ seconds for $p>0,k>1$) or paste the last thing she copied (which takes $p$ seconds). This can be formulated using the matrix set $COPY=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  1 & 0\\
  1 & 0
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$ and $PASTE=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  1 & 1\\
  0 & 1
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$ and $w_1=pk$ and $w_2=p$ and a set of initial vectors consisting just of $v_1=\big(\begin{smallmatrix}
  1\\
  0
\end{smallmatrix}\big)$. We then want to maximize the first coordinate of a vector by multiplying by $COPY$ and $PASTE$ while keeping the cost/sum of weights low.

By generalizing this problem to the format above, I am hoping to see if anyone has studied this class of problems, and to uncover any research that may have already been done in this area.

Comment: What do you mean by the *weight* of a matrix? Is this just some arbitrary positive number?

Comment: Yes. The weight of a matrix is just a positive real number we assign to the given matrix.